# Mysql between query not working

Tags: mysql, date, between

I am using mysql. I want to display records between two dates.
I searched through web and found that mysql's date format is yyyy/mm/dd.
so I am writing query as follows,

```
select 
    * 
from tbl_reservation 
where 
    current_date between '2014-03-28' and '2014-03-26';
```

But, I don't know why it is not working. "col_date" has DATE datatype. I am not storing time in it.

Let me give you some idea what i have done at back end,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date curr_date=new Date();
String compareDate=sdf.format(curr_date);
```

And I am storing this value in "col_date". Is it happening because of this processing?

Thanks for your valuable time in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `BETWEEN`, use least date first, latest date next

It should be:

```
select * from tbl_reservation 
where col_date between '2014-03-26'  -- least date
                   and '2014-03-28'; -- latest date
```

Comment: Yes friend. I did that, but its not working still. I have edited my question. Please go through it. I have explained back end code too. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Write lower date value first.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_reservation WHERE col_date BETWEEN '2014-03-26' AND '2014-03-28'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set column name as `current_date`. Actually it is a function in mysql. So i can not use `current_date` as column name. Thanks I learned something new today. Thank you Masters.

Comment: If the problem was the name of the column, I'd advice you to edit your question using the original name. There you used `col_date` not `current_date`, so as it stands now, it does not represent a reproduceable problem, nor reflect your solution in any way.

Comment: I did it. Thanks for noticing me.